# Fourier in Mathematica different from octave

Tags: fourier-analysis

First I create a table of `sin(x)` within `0, 10`

```
In[97]:= Table[Sin[1.0 x], {x, 0, 10}]
Out[97]= {0.,0.841471,0.909297,0.14112,-0.756802,-0.958924,-0.279415,0.656987,0.989358,0.412118,-0.544021}
```

Then I try to apply fft on this data ([wolfram Link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier%5B%7B0.,%200.841471,%200.909297,%20%20%20%20%200.14112,%20-0.756802,%20-0.958924,%20-0.279415,%200.656987,%200.989358,%20%20%20%20%200.412118,%20-0.544021%7D%5D))

```
In[100]:= Fourier[{0.,0.841471,0.909297,0.14112,-0.756802,-0.958924,-0.279415,0.656987,0.989358,0.412118,-0.544021}]//MatrixForm
Out[100]//MatrixForm= (
     0.425489 +0.I
     0.570407 -0.270821I
    -0.860518+1.09804I
    -0.0342615+0.218599I
     0.0450821 +0.095328I
     0.0665458 +0.0283187I
     0.0665458 -0.0283187I
     0.0450821 -0.095328I
    -0.0342615-0.218599I
    -0.860518-1.09804I
     0.570407 +0.270821I)
```

I do the same using [octave](http://octave-online.net/)

```
fft([0.;0.841471;0.909297;0.14112;-0.756802;-0.958924;-0.279415;0.656987;0.989358;0.412111])
ans =

   1.41119 + 0.00000i
   1.89183 + 0.89821i
  -2.85402 - 3.64178i
  -0.11363 - 0.72501i
   0.14952 - 0.31617i
   0.22071 - 0.09392i
   0.22071 + 0.09392i
   0.14952 + 0.31617i
  -0.11363 + 0.72501i
  -2.85402 + 3.64178i
   1.89183 - 0.89821i
```

**Which one of them is correct ?**

UPDATE

using FourierParameters as suggested, However [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier%5B%7B0.,%200.841471,%200.909297,%20%20%20%20%200.14112,%20-0.756802,%20-0.958924,%20-0.279415,%200.656987,%200.989358,%20%20%20%20%200.412118,%20-0.544021%7D,%20FourierParameters-%3E%20%7B1,-1%7D%5D) online gives different result

```
In[101]:= Fourier[{0.,0.841471,0.909297,0.14112,-0.756802,-0.958924,
                     -0.279415,0.656987,0.989358,0.412118,-0.544021},
                  FourierParameters->{1,-1}] // MatrixForm
Out[101]//MatrixForm= (
     1.41119  +0.I
     1.89183  +0.898211I
    -2.85402  -3.64178I
    -0.113633 -0.725012I
     0.149521 -0.316167I
     0.220708 -0.0939226I
     0.220708 +0.0939226I
     0.149521 +0.316167I
    -0.113633 +0.725012I
    -2.85402  +3.64178I
     1.89183 -0.898211I)
```

But why these are different ?

Comment: Take a look at the Details section in the documentation of `Fourier`, paying special attention to `FourierParameters`, and compare the formula there with the one given e.g. by [the MATLAB docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) (Octave copies MATLAB.)

Comment: All of the results are rounded, so the Wolfram alpha online result is the same as octave, but for the formatting and number of digits. Are you sure you calculated the same thing with numpy? According to this site, https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/08/28/understanding-the-fft/ numpy should also use FourierParameters->{1,-1}.

Comment: Sorry the numpy one was wrong, Thank You

Comment: This is covered in the answer [Fourier transforms do not return the expected result](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118092/731) in the *What are the most common pitfalls awaiting new users?* Q&A.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read the docs for `Fourier`. There are different conventions, and *Mathematica* lets you choose which convention you want using the `FourierParameters` option. For example, to reproduce Octave's (and MATLAB's) convention, use

```
dat = Table[Sin[1.0 x], {x, 0, 10}]
Fourier[dat, FourierParameters -> {1, -1}]
```

This is what the docs call the "signal processing convention". The meaning of the options is given in the help file under details and options where it says:

[image]

So for example, with $a=1$, the term outside the sum is $1/n^0 = 1$ and there is no scaling on the forward Fourier transform. With $a=-1$, the scaling would be $1/n$. Similarly for $b$, though it appears in the exponent of the `e` in the sum. $b=-1$ means the forward transform has a minus sign in the exponent while $b=1$ means it has a plus sign.

Comment: Yes, that -1 is important, even though it makes no difference with the OP's input :-)

Comment: I've often wished that "signal processing" was the default!

Comment: Would you mind explaining the difference between the conversions ?

Comment: I added a bit about the meaning of the options, mostly cribbed from the documentation.